# Psychological aspects to time organisation

Tags: productivity, psychologist-psychology

I am a very lazy person and I'm constantly procrastinating and wasting my time. I've come to realise that allocating certain time slots of the day may benefit my day-to-day production postively.

This would include allowing a certain amount of time for reading, studying, relaxing, sleeping etc.

Are there any major psychological advantages and disadvantages to precisely scheduling my day, in such a way that I'm very strict as to when I allocate time for specific tasks and activities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are. The following are advantages.

**Less Stress** – Managing your time can directly reduce your stress level. Fewer surprises. Fewer tight deadlines. Less rushing from task-to-task and place-to-place.

**Get More Done** – Of course, being productive is one of the main goals of time management. When you are aware of what you need to do, you are able to better manage your workload. You will be able to get more (of the right tasks) done in less time.

**Less Rework** – Being organized results in less rework and mistakes. Forgotten items, details, and instructions lead to extra work. How often do you have to do a task more than once? Or make an extra trip because you forget something?

**Less Life Friction and Problems** – How often do you create your own problems? Whether it is a forgotten appointment or missed deadline, not managing your time results in increased life friction. Avoid creating your own problems by planning and preparing for your day.

**More Free Time** – We can’t create more time, but you can make better use of it by managing your time. Even simple actions like shifting your commute or getting your work done early can produce more leisure time in your life.

**Less Wasted Time** – When you know what you need to do, you waste less time in idle activities. Instead of wondering what you should be doing next, you can already be a step ahead of your work.

**More Opportunities** – Being on top of your time and work produces more opportunities. The early bird always has more options. As well, luck favors the prepared.

**Improves Your Reputation** – Your time management reputation will proceed you. At work and in life you will be known as reliable. No one is going to question whether you are going to show up, do what you say you are going to do, or meet that deadline.

**Less Effort** – A common misconception is that time management takes extra effort. To the contrary, proper time management makes your life easier. Things take less effort, whether it is packing for that trip or finishing up that project.

**More Time Where it Matters** – Managing your time is allotting your time where it has the most impact. Time management allows you to spend your time on the things that matter most to you.

***Disadvantages*** include Non-clear objectives, Mismanagement, Obstacles, Inactivity, Load of different works at one time, Fatigue and stress become part of life, No time for recreation.

Reference : https://timemanagementninja.com/2013/10/the-top-10-life-benefits-of-time-management/

http://content.wisestep.com/top-advantages-disadvantages-time-management/

Comment: Do "**more free time**" and the **disadvantage** in your post contradict each other?

Comment: Nope. Since we manage time effective will get more free time. This is what I mean as "More free time".

Comment: How would you separate recreation and leisure? To me they're pretty much the same things.

Comment: Leisure is the spare or rest time in the daily life of a person when he is not occupied by work, studies, sleep etc.Recreation is indulging in thrilling and exciting activities, to derive some pleasure and have fun in one’s leisure time. Simply say, "Recreation is doing activities that recharge and freshens up in one’s leisure time".